# Speeding up (automating) QGIS georeferencing process?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I georeference a lot of maps with QGis using a combination of visible street intersections on paper maps and right clicking on those intersections inside of maps.google.com and clicking "what's here?", then copying and pasting the latitude and longitude information into the Georeferencer program by hand.

Does anyone out there have any procedures to speed up their georeferencing efforts?

I've done this so many times I'm a little embarassed as a programmer that I'm doing it in such a pedestrian manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use the Georeferencer GDAL plugin and  Quick Map Services as this allows me to use the Google maps (or OSM or whatever) base map inside QGIS and clicking on a point in the image automatically brings up a window to click on the map and fills it all in for me.

I can even georeference in a local projection rather than WGS84 or EPSG:3857.

[image]

Comment: heads up to everyone out there, use the default CRS for whatever aerial layer you use for reference! I transformed mine to epsg:4326 and got a very consistent x axis error for all my gcps

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are switching between a browser and QGIS. It would be faster to stay inside of QGIS and use a background aerial layer, zoom to the general location of the image and then fit the image to your current view extent. Then you can quickly add control points between the aerial background and your map.

Programatically georeferencing maps I don't know. ArcGIS can give this a good effort but it isn't perfect. Not sure about QGIS.